# why is my dynamic style reloaded in Angular 6 when a click a button that has nothing to do with it

Tags: css, angular

I have some dynamic stylesheets that I load based on some state of my Angular app (think theming for different users).

I have only recently ported this code to Angular 6 (from AngularJS) and it took me a few days to realize that my pages were flickering when I would click a checkbox or even expand/collapse a region via a button.

I did some digging and found out that my style is being reloaded seemingly for no reason.

You can see the simple [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-od6dgx)

The gist of the code is:

```
// app.component.ts

//...
style: 'a' | 'b';

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

getStyleUrl() {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`assets/${this.style || 'a'}.css`);
}

doSomething() {
  console.log(`done!`);
}
```

the HTML:

```
// app.component.html
<link rel="stylesheet" [href]="getStyleUrl()">
...
<a type="button" (click)="style = 'a'">A</a><br>
<a type="button" (click)="style = 'b'">B</a><br>
<a type="button" (click)="doSomething()">B</a><br>
```

You can see below that every time I click the `no-op` button, which does not change the URL of the style, it still reloads the style.

[image: style reload on no-op]

is `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()` returning a different URL at every call? so change detection causes it to reload? How else could I load that style dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't call the function from the template; it gets triggered on every CD cycle which is usually more often than you anticipate. And yes -- the sanitizer returns a new object every time it's invoked, since it's a pure function.

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  this.styleUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`assets/${this.style || 'a'}.css`);
}

<link rel="stylesheet" [src]="styleUrl">
```

Comment: Genius! I knew this was something silly. You're so quick to answer, SO won't even let me mark it as the answer yet... I will come back in 10 minutes.